# how to build intent in activity and receive from fragment

Tags: android, android-intent

i am new to Android. Is what i am trying to do is stupid? 
I have build an intent in an activity (EditPhoto) as follows:

```
            //Defining intent for loading image to the edit page
            Intent recentPhoto = new Intent(this, ImportPhoto.class);

            //Defining byte stream of image chosen
            ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);

            //Transforming image to EditPhoto class in byte stream
            recentPhoto.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());

            //Starting the intent
            startActivity(recentPhoto);
```

And i am trying to receive it from a fragment (FirstFragment) from another activity (ImportPhoto) as shown below:

```
                // Getting the image back imported from EditPhoto page
                final Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().  
                                     getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),
                         0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);

        //Displaying the image in the image viewer
        viewGalleryImages.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

As fragment class is static, it says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getIntent() from the type Activity".

I tried using bundles and set arguments to fragment but again suffer from the same problem.

Also, i have tried getActivity().getIntent.... and also casting getActivity like this ((ImportPhoto)getActivity()).getIntent... Both way runs the application but crashes it.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this wrong you dont send intents to fragments.

When you create the fragment you do something like this

```
Fragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
fragTransaction.add(fragment,null).commit;
```

When you create the fragment create an instance of the class that extends fragment by casting the class to the fragment like this

```
FirstFragment first = (FirstFragment)fragment;
```

then in your FirstFragment class create a method to take in the photo or whatever ad access it using the `first` value you just created

```
first.setPhoto(image);
```

Anytime you need a fragment to communicate with an activity you need to create a callback to the activity from the fragment read up on fragments [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)